# How do you set up a ubuntu server so that it can recieve and run code remotely

Tags: server, remote-access

I've gotten my hands on two older (i.e. ~2 years old) department towers that I came across when setting up our new workstations that I want to turn into servers that people can run code on remotely. The code would mostly consist of Python (2 and 3) and Java. Being able to run those is a must, but other languages would be nice. I thought here would be a good as place as any to ask where I would start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest `openssh`. As an SSH server, you can remotely execute commands (including `python`, `java`, `ruby` etc) in the terminal.

You can install it by entering `sudo apt-get install openssh-server` in the terminal or by clicking the link below:

[image: Install via the software center]

Setup instructions and documentation can be found on the [Ubuntu Help Page](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/openssh-server.html).

Comment: That simple, huh?